# I have downloaded python 3.8.5 but my still version seeing me 3.7.4. Why?

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I have trouble with my python version. I have downloaded latest version 3.8.5 but my command prompt seeing me that still version is 3.7.4. Help me.

C:\Users\Life Hacker>python --version
Python 3.7.4

Comment: change the PATH environment variable to point to the right version.

Answer (score 0):

First, Uninstall the older version of Python. Then install the latest one. After installing check the environment variables in your settings.

1. Right-click on My Computer and select Properties.
2. Go to the Advanced tab.
3. Click the Environment Variables button. The Environment Variables dialog opens.
   Check the path for python compiler is properly specified or not!